# How to prove `theorem : ¬ ⊤ ≡ ⊥` in Agda?

Tags: logic, proof, agda

Following *The Haskell Road to Logic, Maths and Programming*, one can find p.48 **Theorem 2.12.1** `¬ ⊤ ≡ ⊥` and its converse `¬ ⊥ ≡ ⊤`

The book uses Haskell and assumes

1. `⊥ = False`
2. `⊤ = True`

which would yield the Agda type `theorem : (p q : Bool) → not p  ≡ q` which is trivial to prove via `refl`.

However, can one prove the original theorem without assuming 1 and 2?

trying

```
-- from software foundations (https://plfa.github.io/Negation/)
postulate
  excluded-middle : ∀ {A : Set} → A ⊎ ¬ A

theorem : ¬ ⊤ ≡ ⊥
theorem x = {!!}
```

of course yields no solution, since we can't construct `⊥`, so I guess a proof by contradiction is needed? Also, am I correct that this assumes the law of the excluded middle, which is therefore required as an additional postulate?

Agda says:

> I'm not sure if there should be a case for the constructor refl,
>   because I get stuck when trying to solve the following unification
>   problems (inferred index ≟ expected index):
>     ⊤ ≟ ⊥
>   when checking that the expression ? has type ⊥

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `¬ ⊤ ≡ ⊥` is `¬ (⊤ ≡ ⊥)`, then @Andras Kovacs answer suits for both `¬ ⊤ ≡ ⊥` and `¬ ⊥ ≡ ⊤`. If `¬ ⊤ ≡ ⊥` is `(¬ ⊤) ≡ ⊥`, then the proof requires an equality of types. Usually you should be fine with the proof of existence of isomorphism between `¬ ⊤` and `⊥`.

The proof for `(¬ ⊤) ≡ ⊥` establishes that `¬ ⊤` is not inhabited.

The proof for `(¬ ⊥) ≡ ⊤` then essentially establishes the fact that `¬ ⊥` has only one function, `id` (hence is isomorphic to all types containing a single element).

All of the following can be constructed using some standard Agda functions, but here the self-sufficient bunch of definitions needed to prove the existence of such isomorphisms. Note `False` and `True` are types, not boolean values. Also, extensionality axiom is needed to be able to prove the second theorem, because `¬ ⊥` is a function.

```hs
data False : Set where

data True : Set where
  tt : True

data _==_ {A : Set} (x : A) : A -> Set where
   refl : x == x

false-elim : {A : Set} -> False -> A
false-elim ()

id : {A : Set} -> A -> A
id x = x

const : {A B : Set} -> B -> A -> B
const x _ = x

ap : {A B : Set} -> (A -> B) -> A -> B
ap = id

ap' : {A B : Set} -> A -> (A -> B) -> B
ap' x f = f x

infixl 4 _==_

data Isomorphism {A B : Set} (f : A -> B) (g : B -> A) : Set where
   iso : ((x : B) -> f (g x) == id x) ->
         ((x : A) -> g (f x) == id x) -> Isomorphism f g

Not : Set -> Set
Not A = A -> False

not-True-iso-False : Isomorphism (ap' tt) false-elim
not-True-iso-False = iso (\x -> false-elim {ap' tt (false-elim x) == id x} x)
                         \not-true -> false-elim (not-true tt)

-- extensionality: if functions produce equal results for all inputs, then the functions are equal
postulate ext : {A B : Set} -> (f g : A -> B) -> ((x : A) -> f x == g x) -> f == g

not-False-iso-True : Isomorphism {Not False} {True} (const tt) (const id)
not-False-iso-True = iso is-true is-not-false where
   is-true : (x : True) -> const tt (const {True} (id {Not False})) == id x
   is-true tt = refl
   is-not-false : (x : Not False) -> const id (const {Not False} tt) == id x
   is-not-false x = ext (const id (const {Not False} tt)) x \()
```

---

Now, if we define `_==_` for any level of type universe, then we can introduce the axiom about type equality: if two types have an isomporphism, then they are equal.

```hs
open import Agda.Primitive
data _==_ {a : Level} {A : Set a} (x : A) : A -> Set a where
   refl : x == x

postulate iso-is-eq : {A B : Set} {f : A -> B} {g : B -> A} ->
                      Isomorphism f g -> A == B

not-True-is-False : (Not True) == False
not-True-is-False = iso-is-eq not-True-iso-False

not-False-is-True : (Not False) == True
not-False-is-True = iso-is-eq not-False-iso-True
```

Comment: Or use `--cubical` and prove the equation as-it-is.

Comment: @AndrásKovács :) That'd be the next level challenge

Answer (score 7):

This is provable in plain Agda without postulates. The solution is that `⊤ ≡ ⊥` allows us to turn any proof of `⊤` into a proof of `⊥`.

```
open import Data.Unit
open import Data.Empty
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Relation.Nullary

theorem : ¬ (⊤ ≡ ⊥)
theorem eq = subst (λ A → A) eq tt
```